# Dell Inspiron laptop not switching on

Tags: laptop, dell-inspiron

I have a [Dell Insprion 1525](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron#Inspiron_1525_.28Inspiron_15.29) latop which is not switching on.
The power adapter light is glowing, but I do not see any light glowing on the laptop.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the battery for 5 mins then reinsert it. That should do the trick

Comment: That really worked! But is this a problem related to battery?

Comment: Its and yes and no question. If its a battery problem, the connections from the PC to the battery where misaligned an removing and reinserting helped. If not, its a OS related problem where the system wanted to be 'reset'. - Could you please vote my answer up if it helped, thnx

Comment: - I meant, select it as the answer

Comment: How exactly we can find out if its a OS related problem and is there way we can check the date and time the system got reset?

Comment: I am curious now, do laptops have CMOS batteries in them or do they just use the main laptop battery?