# Troubleshooting Windows Vista booting problem

Tags: windows, windows-vista, dell-inspiron

I have a [Dell Inspiron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron) laptop which is loaded with Windows Vista Home.

I had previously reported a problem with the laptop not switching on, which got fixed. Link: [Dell Inspiron laptop not switching on](https://superuser.com/questions/171877/dell-inspiron-laptop-not-switching-on).

I would like to trouble shoot if this is related to the OS. Do you have useful suggestions regarding the same?

Comment: Troubleshoot what problem? Please explain in detail

Comment: I have explained the problem here a solution was given but would like to know more about the cause of the problem  - http://superuser.com/questions/171877/dell-inspiron-laptop-not-switching-on.

Answer (score 0):

#### What was the cause of the problem described in "[Dell Inspiron laptop not switching on](https://superuser.com/questions/171877/dell-inspiron-laptop-not-switching-on.)"?

The answer is, it's related to the hardware of the system. If the system will not turn on, it's because of hardware reasons. There are a few things that happen before even Windows Vista begins to load. It starts with the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS). It talks to the hardware and tell the computer to begin loading the operating system.. So, update the BIOS first and foremost. Below is a link to the driver page. I would download any drivers that are out-of-date. Specifically download and install the BIOS and chipset drivers. If this doesn't fix it then call the tech support and have the laptop replaced.

[**Dell's official Inspiron 1525 driver page**](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&ServiceTag=&SystemID=INS_PNT_PM_1525&os=WLH&osl=en&catid=&impid=)